# Ping a windows phone

Tags: windows-10-mobile, networking, lumia-550

Is it possible to make a windows phone reply to a `ping` (i.e. ICMP echo requests)?

I tried and mine doesn't -- at least it seems it doesn't when the screen is locked, perhaps to save power. Is this true? (If so, I guess it would not be possible to change this behavior.)

Comment: My Lumia 950 responds to ping on Wi-Fi, regardless of whether the screen is on or off. Doesn't your phone? Or did you mean on mobile data?

Comment: On WiFi. A few seconds after I lock the screen it stops replying to ping, and it resumes as soon as I press the button to unlock.